# Start SSH session in ConEmu using Keepass 2

Tags: windows, conemu, keepass, git-bash

I am using Keepass 2 to store my SSH login credentials.  Keepass has the ability to run commands and insert usernames, passwords, etc. into that command, so you can click on a web site credential and have it open that page in a browser.

http://keepass.info/help/base/autourl.html

I'd like to do that with my SSH logins.  In ConEmu, I'm running Git Bash, which includes the OpenSSH command line client.  I'd like to have Keepass run a command which opens a new terminal in ConEmu, and starts SSH, passing in the IP, user, and password from the KeePass database.

ConEmu has a lot of handy command line switches:

https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Command_Line

But I can't figure out how to make those switches open a terminal and run ssh.  Here's my attempt:

`ConEmu64.exe /cmd "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i "ssh bob@10.1.2.3"`

But these are the results I get:

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.9.4-preview20140611)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
sh.exe": ssh bob@10.1.2.3: No such file or directory


Current directory:
C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu

Command to be executed:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i "ssh bob@10.1.2.3"


ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=127.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

I tried a couple variations, but didn't get any closer.  It seems clear to me that I do not properly understand how the ConEmu command line switches, or how to pass a command into my Git Bash session.  Any tips will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with ConEmu switches. The error is showing by "git"! You need to examining its (`sh.exe`) switches!

```
ConEmu64.exe /cmd "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "ssh bob@10.1.2.3"
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks.  The nesting of having ConEmu call, Git Bash, which called ssh was a bit much for me, and I got a little confused.  I couldn't understand why bash would see the 'Command to be executed' as having its own path.  But I'm guessing the first 4 lines were Bash output, and the last 6 were ConEmu output?  At any rate, adding the -c fixed it, and now I can use KeePass to start SSH sessions in ConEmu by simply hitting Ctrl + U.  Love it!!!